# Trying to append True or False to a table based on index

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of true or false values called x (size 458)

```
x = [False, True, False, True, True, False, False ...]
```

And a list of indices called y. (size 1754)

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, ...]
```

What I am trying to do is create a new list of True or False values that correspond to list x. For example, a successful execution of my code based on the values in x and y would look be the creation of a new list called z, size 1754, that looks like this

```
z = [False, True, False, False, True, True, True, ...]
```

So far I have tried this with the following code

```
z = []
for i in y:
   for index, value in enumerate(x):
       if i == index:
           z.append(value)
```

However, z is being returned as a blank list. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since y contains the indices of x, then a list of comprehension on y, and a direct access to x's index can solve the problem in `O(len(y))`. So, I think this should be enough.:

```
z = [x[i] for i in y]
```

---

Example:

```
x = [False, True, False, True, True]
y = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
z = [x[i] for i in y]
```

Output:

```
[False, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Comment: @flannel_bioinformatician are the numbers in `y` in string format or in int format?

Comment: @flannel_bioinformatician if they are in string format you can apply the following to convert them to int, before applying my proposed solution `y = [int(i) for i in y]`

Comment: You might want to show Flannel_bioinformatician the equivalent code in a for loop with an append in case they are unfamiliar with list comprehensions.

Comment: they were str format and I changed them to int. However now I get the error that list index is out of range

Comment: That would mean that you probably have a value in y that is greater than the last index of x (458 - 1) -> 457 (since lists are 0 indexed)

Comment: @flannel_bioinformatician alexanderhurst is right. This is a corner case that you need to define how to handle. Maybe by setting false when the index doesn't exist in x or by skipping that element from y altogether